# unexpected results using group by in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, group-by

Am just learning how to use hibernate to deal with databases and I came across something struck me as weird 
I was trying to get a list of objects from a table grouped by a foreign key 
student has (name,ID,department)
department(name,ID) ... so this is the code I wrote to get it

```
String x = "FROM Student s group by department";
 List<Object> obj = session.createQuery(x).list();
```

but I was surprised t find that it returned only one student from each department not a bunch grouped as I expected?

Am I doing something wrong here?

how do I get a list of student in each department grouped?

I appreciate any help that is provided :)

Answer (score 0):

The **group by** clause is designed to work with agregate functions.
For example:

```
x = "select s.age, count(s) from Student s group by department";
```

You will receive groups: {age, number of students with this age}

See this example:

[hql gruping example](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-grouping)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [reference documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-grouping):

> Neither the group by clause nor the order by clause can contain
>   arithmetic expressions. Hibernate also does not currently expand a
>   grouped entity, so you cannot write **group by cat** if all properties of
>   cat are non-aggregated. You have to list all non-aggregated properties
>   explicitly.

What you need can be resolved with a bidirectional mapping instead. So you have a @ManyToOne association from Student to Department and a @OneToMany(mappedBy) back from Department to Student.

Then you fetch all Departments along with their Students:

```
select distinct d
from Department d
join fetch d.students s
```

which will return a List of Departments where the Department.students list will also be fetched.